# Why can't I find app.locals in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm working with express/node/jade and have build a module for some variables.

I have this line in my app.js `app.locals.GVs = require('./utils/globalvars.js');`

and this is my jade

```
extends ../layout

block content
  h1 Edit - Change Your Profile
  p There will hopefully be a form to change users here.
  form(id='form',action='')
    include ./includes/user-form.jade
    input(type='reset', value='Clear')
    input(type='submit', value='Update')
  script.
    //Wait for document to load.
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#firstname').val('#{data.firstname}');
      $('#lastname').val('#{data.lastname}');
      $('#username').val('#{data.username}');
      $('#phone').val('#{data.phone}');
      $('#email').val('#{data.email}');

      //Once form is submitted thisUserData (UserData) is created.
      $('#form').submit(function(){
        // creates the variable thisUserData as a new UserData.
        var thisUserData = new GVs.UserData($('#firstname').val(), $('#lastname').val(), $('#username').val(), $('#password').val(), $('#confirmpassword').val(), $('#phone').val(), $('#email').val());
        //POST call; Sends thisUserData and alerts that a user was updated.
        $.post('/user/edit', {userFormData: thisUserData}, function(data){
          alert("User updated!");
        });
      });
    });
```

I get an error on when I call GVs `var thisUserData = new GVs.UserData(...);`

I also tries passing it the same way i did with "data" but it did the same thing.

EDIT: I tried to see if I could get GVs in the jade file like so

```
p There will hopefully be a form to change users here.
```

became this

```
p There will hopefully be a form to change users here. '#{GVs.UserData}'
```

and its there, why can I get it in jade but not in script.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass variables between client-side JS and server-side, because client side don't know about node.js global vars. For example:

```
extends ../layout

block content
  h1 Edit - Change Your Profile
  p There will hopefully be a form to change users here.
  form(id='form',action='')
    include ./includes/user-form.jade
    input(type='reset', value='Clear')
    input(type='submit', value='Update')
  script.
    var GVs = !{JSON.stringify(GVs)};
    //Wait for document to load.
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#firstname').val('#{data.firstname}');
      $('#lastname').val('#{data.lastname}');
      $('#username').val('#{data.username}');
      $('#phone').val('#{data.phone}');
      $('#email').val('#{data.email}');

      //Once form is submitted thisUserData (UserData) is created.
      $('#form').submit(function(){
        // creates the variable thisUserData as a new UserData.
        var thisUserData = new GVs.UserData($('#firstname').val(), $('#lastname').val(), $('#username').val(), $('#password').val(), $('#confirmpassword').val(), $('#phone').val(), $('#email').val());
        //POST call; Sends thisUserData and alerts that a user was updated.
        $.post('/user/edit', {userFormData: thisUserData}, function(data){
          alert("User updated!");
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: This works for the variables I have in that module but I cant access any of the function that are in it.

Comment: @Devcon if you want same functions on client and server you can use browserify http://browserify.org/

Comment: Thanks for the help @vanadium23 I got it working with webpack.